# jquery click the highest parent input's child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to click the first input checkbox when I click the second one.

```
<li>
  <div>
     <input type='checkbox' value='x'/>
  </div>

  <ul>
     <li>
        <ul>
             <li>
                 <div>
                     <input type='checkbox' id='check' value='b'/>
                  </div>
              </li>

        </ul>

     </li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

doing this does not help:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
  $('this').parents('li #parent').children('div').find('input').click();
});
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#check').click(function(){
  $('#parent').find('input').first().click();
});
```

if you use `parent` as class

```
<li class='parent'>
```

Then you can do this -

```
$('#check').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.parent').find('input').first().click();
});
```

Comment: Given that there's an `id`, why use `closest()`?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the parent id is generated dynamically

Comment: @DavidThomas because many people use duplicate id as it causes no problem

Comment: is there anyway to not to use the id at all?

Comment: so basically we need either id or class for the first li to address it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since id is unique there is no need to look for any parents, you can directly use the `id`

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li[id]').find('input').first().click();
});
```

Comment: thats what i thought :) elegant!

Comment: sorry didnt mention the id is generated dynamically

Comment: @ComeRun then what about the id `check` is it also dynamic

Comment: @ComeRun in that case we will go with the closest `li` which has an `id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Give the first checkbox its own ID. Then you can use

```
$('#firstcheck').prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, given that the `id` is dynamically generated:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div[id]').find('input').first().click();
});
```

If, as you note in comments to other answers, the `id` for `#check` is *also* dynamic I'd strongly suggest adding a consistent class-name to the `input`-element in order to bind the `click()` event-handler. Otherwise you'll end up having to check the 'depth', or the number of ancestors, in order to decide which should *be* clicked, and which should *trigger* the click event-handler.

Comment: Yes, yes it does. You could instead use a specific `class`, or other `data-*` attribute, but there has to be some consistent way to identify the elements you're binding to and traversing.

Answer (score 0):

This will work without an ID, but as David Thomas mentioned, it's more efficient to use an ID.

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('li').last().find('div:first input').click();
});
```